# Exclude Specific User From '/var/log/auth.log'

Tags: ubuntu, logging, sshd, vps

I am currently setting up a VPS and was wondering if there is any way at all for me to exclude a specific user from being logged to `/var/log/auth.log`?

Doing the same for `lastlog` and every other log file that is somehow affected by `sshd` would be even better.

I know I can `/dev/null/` the entire log file, but this would obviously break `fail2ban` and similar packages.

I have come across a solution that relies on a cron job cutting out the offending parts, but this seems a little dodgy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to tamper with audit data. By design this is very difficult to do (I would say almost impossible) as otherwise what would be the point of having audit logs?

If you want to spy on your users then you have to consider law in your country as well as technical difficulties.

I'm afraid that you are looking for a dodgy solution which likely will be difficult to achieve.

Or just install rootkit...

Comment: i simply don't want to be logged on my own server. this has nothing to do with 'spying on my users'? there's no one but me.

Comment: @house If there's no one but you, couldn't you just ignore these logs and log entries?

Comment: @Daniel it's just for peace of mind, really. i like my privacy :) – it was possible to exclude cron, so i was hoping there'd be an easy way for individual users as well.